# Practices for managing complexity of meta-programming (AOP/reflection/macros) techniques

Tags: java, macros, clojure, lisp, aop

**Aspects, Macros, Reflection, and other niceties - the good parts**

I've noticed that "meta programming" tricks (in the clojure world, functions have meta data, in the oo world, we have concepts like reflection, AOP, etc...) can be a good way to decouple and extend functionality of existing code, without editing it.  Such tricks allow us to intercept, redirect, and wrap functional peices of our code so it can be extended in a highly dynamic way.

**The scary part**

However, as many have claimed - overuse of macros can make code difficult to understand.  The "blackboard" software architecture pattern, where several agents modify or edit a common resource can be dangerous if we dont manage the creation of those agents carefully.  Finally, I would informally note that the long standing popularity of C++ and java is, at least partially due to the fact that they are "no-surprises" languages - where code is clear, explicit, and procedural.**

**The problem : The promise of dynamic code injection techniques for reducing boiler plate and decoupling feature sets requires a "new" way of thinking about documentation, class design, and software engineering ?**

**My Questions**

Does the way we document/deploy normal code, manage source packages, integrate libraries requires different or new techniques when we begin accomodating meta-programming methods in conjunction with our more traditional OO methodologies ?

For example, Should we consider the use of meta programming as an alternative to other, more conventional OO programming techniques ?

Are there a general set of known, red flags introduced by meta-programming  -- and  how can we avoid them ?

What are best use cases for the use of aspects, reflection, and other dynamic software techniques ?

Answer (score 1):

I find that AOP is something that need to be used very carefully in a software project and have a well defined purpose. I find it is useful for some boiler plate processes like transaction demarcation, security and logging but it is really easy to get yourself in trouble with AOP and it can become a major source of accidental complexity.

Answer (score 1):

"It depends" :) ... That's what is probably the best answer for all *subjective* questions in programming world.

I would suggest that before going to use any of the technique like AOP or DI, please give it a very serious though in respect to whether you really really need it. We as programmers tends to gets very fascinated by these new tricks and techniques which makes us see beauty (superficial) in code. The real beauty of code that we should strive for is simplicity and nothing else.

Remember every new trick/technique/framework you add to a system will increase the complexity of the system (probably exponentially).

I personally go by the idea of: Build Programs not Applications, Build libraries not frameworks.

Comment: Just curious, what's the difference between "programs" and "applications"?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quote in ([SICP](http://deptinfo.unice.fr/~roy/sicp.pdf)) that might be relevant to the discussion:

> "It is no exaggeration to regard this as the most fundamental idea in programming:
>   The evaluator, which determines the meaning of expressions in a programming language, is just another program.
>   To appreciate this point is to change our images of ourselves as programmers. We come to see ourselves as designers of languages, rather than only users of languages designed by others."